# 401 Unauthorized after release site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have my web api which uses such code to get data from other api and do some operations with it :

```
var credential = new NetworkCredential("login", "password");
            var myCache = new CredentialCache();
            myCache.Add(uri, "Negotiate", credential);
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            handler.Credentials = myCache;
            var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
            var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(GetEmployeesUrl);
            employees = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<EmployeeDto>>(response);
```

When I was debugging this code with `IIS Express` on my local host it's pretty good works and give me OK response from server. When I tried to deploy my api to real `IIS` this `var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(GetEmployeesUrl);`always returns `401 Unauthorized error`.
Have someone some ideas what it can be? I have used webclient and webrequest they worked on my local machine but answer after deploy on server was the same.

Comment: Where did you deploy? IIS? You might have anonymous authentication enabled. You can either disable anonymous authentication from IIS or add [Authorize] attribute on controller of your application.

Comment: Delpoyed on IIS 8.5. When I make request to my API it responsing me, and all is good until I use the method with code which I wrote in my question.

Comment: Can you check your IIS authentication settings?

Comment: Yes, Anonymous enabled asp.net disabled forms disabled widows enabled. This settings you wanted?

Comment: Try disabling anonymous and see if it works.

Comment: Now my API returning 401 error straight in postman.